# Does Shield spell turn a hit into a miss?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

*Shield* spell says

> **Casting Time:** 1 reaction, which you take when you are hit by an attack or targeted by the *magic missile* spell

Let's say I attack with a total attack roll of 16, and target AC is 15. The target then casts *shield*. His AC is now 20.

I have Tavern Brawler feat, which has this benefit:

> When **you hit** a creature with an unarmed strike or an improvised weapon on your turn, you can use a bonus action to attempt to grapple the target.

With my attack roll of 16, against 20, which was a hit, can I use my bonus action to grapple the target?

My player's argument is that the attack hits, then deflected, so it still counts as a hit, and therefore able to use bonus action to grapple. Usually I simply call the attack "a miss", but the argument seems sound. So I need to ask this question:

**Does Shield spell turn a hit into a miss?**